# How to line two buttons at each corner using flex in react js

Tags: css, reactjs

I am preety new to React js .Just started with building a simple react App.
I have two buttons to be placed at each side which I am trying to do with  CSS- flex but unable to acheive.
Can anyone plaese suggest where am I going wrong?

```
      import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@material-ui/core/Toolbar";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";



const styles = {
  root: {
    display:'flex',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width:'100%'
  },

};

class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div className={styles.root}>
   <button>news</button>
   <button >login</button>
</div>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

The two icons i.e. News and Login should be in two corners of the AppBar.

[image: Below is the view I am getting now]

Comment: Can we see a a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Can you pls find it now?

Comment: Can you share your complete `.js` code? Thanks

Comment: Complete Header.js code has been updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `justify-content: space-between`. See css-tricks' awesome guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

However, you must ensure that the flex items are the **direct** children of the flex container (element with display: flex) e.g.

```
<div className="toolbar flex-container">
   <button className="child">news</button>
   <button className="child">login</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Update

You're using `className` when you should be using the `style` attribute. You're setting styles, not a class.

The React code would look something like this:

```
class Header extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const styles = {
      root: {
        display:'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        width:'100%'
      }    
    }

    return (
      <div style={styles.root}>
        <button>news</button>
        <button >login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Header />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

The working Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5rux17en/).

---

Your flex container is too high up in the DOM. Since flex children must be direct descendants of a flex parent, what you have won't work. You would need to move the `display: flex` assignment down to `<Toolbar>`, since it is the *direct* parent of `<Button>` and `<Typography>`. To align two buttons in opposite corners using flex, you can use `justify-content: space-between`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <button>a button</button>
   <button>a button</button>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9n6c4uqf/)

Comment: justifyContent: 'space-between'  is not working in react js

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
display: 'flex',
justify-content: 'space-between',
```

I'm not sure what the syntax is for React.